# Elastic Search scan operation not working

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm performing some operation in Dataflow and putting document in ElasticSearch index.While trying to fetch doc from Kibana, I'm not able to fetch more than 10 records at a time. So I have used scan operation and also provide the size in url, now I'm getting scan operation not supported error.
[image]

```
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "No search type for [scan]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No search type for [scan]"
  },
```

So is there any way to get more than 10 docs from Kibana at the same time. So I'm using Kibana 7.7.0 management. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: after you give `size` with 50 without scan in your normal query what happens ?

Comment: so are you able to get more than 10 docs using size param ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search_type=scan was supported til Elasticsearch v2.1, and then removed.

Probably you're using something higher than ES 2.1.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-request-search-type.html